# React - render functional subcomponent

Tags: reactjs

I am having an issue rendering a React functional component when included as subcompnent in a parent component.

The following renders perfectly:

```
<Table title="Actions">
    <TableHeaderCell>Name</TableHeaderCell>
    <TableHeaderCell>Description</TableHeaderCell>
    <TableHeaderCell>Start Date</TableHeaderCell>
    {data.data.map(item => (
       <TableRow>
          <TableCell>
            {item.name}
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell>
             {item.activity_type.description}
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell>
             {item.startDate}
          </TableCell>

      </TableRow>))}
    </Table>
```

However, when replacing the TableRow with a functional component, then the TableRow is never shown. I created the following Subcomponent:

```
export const ActivityRowComponent = props => {
console.log('entered ActivityRowComponent');
const item = props.activityItem;

return (
    <TableRow>
        <TableCell>
            {item.name}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell>
            {item.activity_type.description}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell>
            {item.startDate}
        </TableCell>

    </TableRow>
);
};


ActivityRowComponent.propTypes = {
   activityItem: PropTypes.object.isRequired,

};
```

and changed the code from above to:

```
<Table title="Actions">
    <TableHeaderCell>Name</TableHeaderCell>
    <TableHeaderCell>Description</TableHeaderCell>
    <TableHeaderCell>Start Date</TableHeaderCell>
    {data.data.map(item => (
       <ActivityRowComponent key={item.activity_id} activityItem={item} />
    ))}
</Table>
```

Note that the "console.log" in "ActivityRowComponent" is never reached. Also, if I set a breakpoint I can observe that "ActivityRowComponent" is never called. And, note that the array data.data has a length of 1.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? What to do in order for the ActivityRowComponent to be rendered?

Comment: What library are you using for table?

Comment: That `activityIem` while using `ActivityRowComponent` is a typo right ? If so, please correct it.

Comment: @Lakshya Thakur: yes, this was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: @ Zunayed Shahriar I am using the so called Watson Health design system - but the error is independent from the component library, as, if I am defining the table row inline (and not with a dedicated sub component), then everything renders fine.

Comment: {data.data.map(item => <ActivityRowComponent key={item.activity_id} activityItem={item} />)} can you do this and check. since its expecting to return the component

Comment: @Ayushi Keshri this leads to the same result.

Comment: @MusterMark {data.data.map(item => { return (<ActivityRowComponent key={item.activity_id} activityItem={item} />) } )} can you try this, plz check the brackets carefully

Comment: @Ayushi Keshri : I tried taking care of the brackets. Same issue. I.e. the return statement and using {} brackets to wrap that return statement, seems to result in no change.

Comment: @MusterMark, check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced your scenario at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-neumann-5tbpc?file=/src/App.js) using HTML table.

And your component is rendering OK. Changed a bit though.

Please check.

Comment: Yes, while export it should be default export. Just reproduce the simplest code to check.

Comment: @Zunayed Shahriar: thank you for your help. It is verty strange, but in my case this is not working. What works is to create a const in the same file as ActivityComponent: 

const activityRow = item => {
        return (
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell>
                    {item.name}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    {item.activity_type.description}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    {item.startDate}
                </TableCell>

            </TableRow>

        );
    };

Comment: @MusterMark, Can't you `export default ActivityRowComponent`, as I did?

Comment: @Zunayed Shahriar: I have this line in the ActivityRowComponent.js:
export default withErrorBoundary(withRouter(ActivityRowComponent));

Comment: Why do you need `withRouter` there?

Comment: @ Zunayed Shahriar: yes, "withrouter" is not necessary there. -->removing it makes no difference. - just tried it

Comment: Can you reproduce your attempt in CodeSandbox or StackBlitz?

Comment: @ Zunayed Shahriar: I just tried to embed the ActivityRowComponent in a simple HTML list (similar to your codeSanfbox example), and this works, i.e. the rows are displayed. Hence, this seems to be a problem with the Table component that I am using. I.e. without using the Table comp, things work.

Comment: Then I need to see Table, TableRow, TableCell, and TableHeaderCell components.